# Mongo Java: How to serialize DBObject as JSON on file?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a document in `MongoDB` as

```
name: name
date_created: date
p_vars: {
   01: {
      a: a,
      b: b,
   }
   02: {
      a: a,
      b: b,
   }
   ....
}
```

represented as `DBObject`

- All `key`, `value` pairs are of type `String`
- I want to serialize this document using Java, Looking at the [api](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/), I did not find anything, How can I serialize a `DBObject` as `JSON` on file?

Answer (score 12):

It seems that [BasicDBObject's toString()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#toString%28%29) method returns the JSON serialization of the object.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the [JSON](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html#serialize%28java.lang.Object%29) class has a method to serialize objects into JSON (as well as to go the [other way](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/) and parse JSON to retrieve a DBObject).

Answer (score 2):

I used the combination of BasicDBObject's toString() and GSON library in the order to get **pretty-printed** JSON:

```
    com.mongodb.DBObject obj = new com.mongodb.BasicDBObject();
    obj.put("_id", ObjectId.get());
    obj.put("name", "name");
    obj.put("code", "code");
    obj.put("createdAt", new Date());

    com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), Map.class)));
```

Comment: Very good! Put aside the creation of the example object, and you have a 2-liner that perfectly does the job with pretty printing.